# What does "me" in the C# lambda expression (_, me) => mean? When should I use me?

Tags: c#, lambda, system.reactive

The complete code is as follows

```
if (CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.ScheduleRequired)
{
    CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.Schedule(this, (_, me) => subscription.Disposable = me.Run(observer, subscription, s => sink.Disposable = s));
}
else
{
    subscription.Disposable = this.Run(observer, subscription, s => sink.Disposable = s);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is... Assuming you understand syntax for lambda expressions - are you asking why one picked "me" as parameter name?

Comment: `me` is just the 2nd parameter to the lambda expression. It doesn't have a special meaning.

Comment: I have removed your second question on the `Shedule` method. Only one question per question, please.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov The code is from Rx, not me. I am trying hard to understand the Rx. The code is defined in a class named **Producer**,  and I wonder whether **me** in **(_, me) =>** represents  **Producer** itself, then it can call the protected method **Run** defined in **Producer** ?

Comment: @Tyoshi - Have you watched the channel 9 msdn videos yet?

Comment: @Enigmativity No. May be I could find the answer.

Comment: @Tyoshi - What answer? To this question? John Sanders has answered this one quite nicely. What are you struggling with to understand in Rx?

Comment: Trying to understand Rx by first reading the source code is like trying to learn to drive a car by first learning how to build an engine... don't start there. Use the library first (and there are plenty of videos on channel9 to help)... then comes back to the source code *much* later. Without the context of using the library (which is quite a learning journey in itself), you are going to have a very hard time.

Comment: @Enigmativity I need to wholly understand the structure of the Rx and add explanation on it.......It may be crazy,but it's a task from my boss!

Comment: @Tyoshi - Now you have two people suggesting you watch the MSDN Channel 9 videos. Have you watched them yet?

Comment: @Enigmativity Sure. And Erik is a fashion gay and his student Smet is so cool !!!!

Comment: @Tyoshi - And did you get a better understanding from the videos?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, but it's a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: @Tyoshi - Yes, because it is really about collections represented in the "time-dimension". You have to think like a time traveller to understand fully.

Comment: @ Thanks a lot for you !

Answer (score 6):

In this example, `me` is just a range variable. It is not a special syntax. It could just as easily have been named `x`.